# How to add a label category after read an email with Mailkit

Tags: c#, .net, mime-types, c#-6.0, mailkit

Actually, I am using MailKit. The program I did about read emails from outlook with ImapClient. The point is what I want to set a label category or color category for the email. I just have the code what shows the Messsage as read. Example:

```
inbox.Store(i, new StoreFlagsRequests(StoreAction.Add, MessageFlags.Seen) {silent:true}
```

If there is some way to resolve it. I appreciate the help, or if there is other solution let me know, please.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard set of keywords for colors, but you would set keywords like this:

```
var keywords = new string[] { "$ColorRed" };
var request = new StoreFlagsRequests(StoreAction.Add, keywords) {
    Silent = true
};
inbox.Store(i, request);
```